# Images not loading in most browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, images

Since this morning I have a problem. Some images(not all) are not loaded throught many websites. They look like this(this one's from fb):

[image]

Same problem happens in chrome and firefox.

I did a scan with Malwarebytes and it found some infections which I deleted, but the problem is the same. I don't use any addons(had adblock but disabled it), and since the problem persists in firefox, too...

Comment: What AV do you use

Comment: I don't use any.

Comment: If you don't use an AV program then how do you know you don't have a virus? Does the same issue also occur in IE? Load [IE up in safe mode](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/run-internet-explorer-9-without-addons-in-safe-mode/). And do you use AdBlock with both Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: How should I remove it? Can they install themselves just like that and screw my images? Adblock only in chrome. Safemode IE seems to work.

Comment: Actually, the virus comment was more of a general question/comment.

Comment: Chrome in safe mode seems to work as well. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get back configuration on IE like this:

Open the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box. To do this, use one of the following steps.
   - Close all Internet Explorer and Explorer windows that are currently open.
Start Internet Explorer.

- Note If you are running Windows 8.1 or Windows 8, start Internet Explorer from the desktop. Changing your settings will affect both Internet Explorer and Internet Explorer that you start from the desktop.
- On the Tools menu, tap or click **Internet options**. If you don't see the Tools menu, press Alt.
- In the Internet Options window, tap or click the Advanced tab.
- Tap or click **Reset**. If you're using Windows Internet Explorer 6, click **Restore Default**.
- In the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box, tap or click **Reset**.
- Note Select the Delete personal settings check box if you also want to remove browsing history, search providers, Accelerators, home pages, Tracking Protection, and ActiveX Filtering data.
  When Internet Explorer finishes applying the default settings, tap or click Close, and then tap or click OK.
  Exit and then start Internet Explorer.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737

Comment: @DaveRook: Thanks for the advice, post updated. 

@ Journeyman Geek: Try to follow the steps and tell us something if works for you...

Comment: That is better, +1

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this is due to an AV; many anti virus programs include an Anti-banner function/module.

Or it's a browser plug-in. I know you said you don't have any addons, but start the browser in safe mode and see if that solves it. If so, you need to see if you actually do have any addon's (and that may be you didn't realise they were there) and disable each add-on one by one until you find the culprit.

You don't have any AV (for what ever reason) so may be some thing installed itself (virus/malware/other) without your permission... Just because you ran a Malware bytes scan doesn't mean it's defiantly going to pick up this issue, especially if the AddOn isn't actually doing any harm (ie, if it's blocking banners)

Comment: I don't use any AV.

Comment: I have only Google docs and adblock, and they are disabled.

Comment: I said earlier that it did solve the problem in SM. But how do I disable them if there are only 2 of them and they are already disabled?

Which AV should I use?

Comment: I don't think you are disabling them, if you were then the safe mode shouldn't work! Or, it's a cache issue... Delete your cache and see if that helps. As for what AV, you need to do your own research, I'm not your shopping advisor.

Comment: I deleted all history, cache, etc.

Comment: If that didn't help, open FireFox, click the Orange firefox button (top left) and click Addons. Now, look under the Addon and Extension tabs. Uninstall the lot.

Comment: Have nothing there.

Comment: Perform a full scan, using an AV program.